# Is it possible to get the event name thats been triggered so I can use it as a string in my method?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm wondering if I run `Backbone.Events.trigger('show:something', this.model);` can I get that event name to pass to method I'm mapping to in my subscribed listener `this.listenTo(Backbone.Events, 'show:something', this.toggle, this);`

`toggle: function(param) {
    // can I get show:something?
}`

Comment: Why do you need to get it..? You know it is always `'show:something'`, right..? When/how is it going to change..?

Comment: Thinking if I have a toggle method where the param could be either hide or show, instead of pass through a hide or show param just use the event?

Comment: I don't see any real benefit. You can trigger `'show:something'` by passing it true/false rather than trying to use same method for different events this way...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer no.

However you can listen to the 'all' event, and the name of the event will be passed to the function as the first param.

```
this.on('all', function(ev, ...) {
  console.log(ev); // the name of the event - show:something in your above example
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot as the only event trigger with this is all as joe fitter described source http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html

But other option is to bind the function you want to be called instead of using the raw function. For example if you are using underscore use this instead of this.toggle

`_.bind(this.toggle, this, 'theEventNameYouWant');`

and let toggle first parameter be

`toggle: function(eventName, param) {`

source http://underscorejs.org/#bind

I am not sure how if you need the second this for the listenTo bind. Get back to me and I will update answer.